# MAX-CUT: are there any algorithms or codes for classical computers, that cater to this specific case?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, graphs, quadratic-programming

**I missed the opportunity to ask this on OR.SE by 24 days! I asked it [at CS.SE on 6 May 2019](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109039/61663) and [OR.SE entered Private Beta on 30 May 2019](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1/727).**

- It's a problem about minimizing a sum of terms that are quadratic in its integer variables.
- It's a QUBO (quadratic unconstrainted binary optimization) problem, and QUBO questions have been fairly well received here at OR.SE (e.g. [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/828/727), [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1380/727), and [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2869/727)) whereas at CS.SE there was interest from only one user that wrote comments.
- While We're beyond the 60-day limit to "migrate" a question, I'll follow [Robert Cartaino's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/391772) and re-ask it here.

---

#### The Question:

A [paper was published recently in Science](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/4/eaav2372/tab-pdf) where the authors minimized the following function:

> $$E_{\text{Ising}}(s) = -\dfrac{1}{2} \Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \Sigma_{j=1}^{N} J_{i,j} s_i s_j,$$
>
> where $s_i$ denotes the $i$th Ising spin, which takes a value of 1 or -1, $s = (s_1 s_2 \cdots s_N)$ is the vector representation of a spin configuration, and $J_{i,j}(=J_{j,i})$ is the coupling coefficient between the $i$th and $j$ spins ($J_{i,i}=0$). The problem is to find a spin configuration minimizing the Ising energy. This problem is mathematically equivalent to a famous combinatorial optimization problem named MAX-CUT (5, 17, 18, 39): divide the nodes of a weighted graph into two groups maximizing the total weight (called "cut value") of the edges cut by the division. By setting the coupling coefficient as $J_{i,j} = - w_{i,j}$ ($w_{i,j} = w_{j,i}$ is the weight between $i$th and $j$th nodes), we can solve MAX-CUT using Ising machines.

In particular, it appears that they are solving instances of weighted MAX-CUT where the input graph is the complete graph on 2000 vertices with edge weights assigned from $\{-1,1\}$ independently and uniformly at random.

They say they found solutions in 0.5 ms and the other specifics such as the criteria for calling something a "solution" are also given.

They say in the abstract that 0.5ms is 10 times faster than the Coherent Ising Machine (a type of ***quantum calculator***), but I would like it to instead be compared to state-of-the-art for conventional algorithms on ***classical computers***.

It should be possible to generate the same type of random instances of MAX-CUT as the authors, and solve the problem with a conventional algorithm for classical computing (e.g. CPUs, GPUs, FPGAs), and compare the performance to what is claimed in the paper, when using the *same* criteria for what is considered a good enough solution.

**Are there any algorithms or codes apart from just general SAT/CSP solvers, that could be applied to this specific problem?**

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [MQLib](https://github.com/MQLib/MQLib), which contains efficient implementations of many published algorithms. [Their paper](https://github.com/MQLib/MQLib/blob/master/paper/SECM_final.pdf) is awesome too.

You can find a lot of code for QUBO online, one of the most publicized being [qbsolv](https://github.com/dwavesystems/qbsolv) from Dwave. It is meant as a demonstrator of how much better quantum algorithms are, and the method is very basic.
In general, I would take any hype on quantum or classical annealers with a hefty grain of salt.

Comment: I gave you +1, but have you ever actually used qbsolv? Furthermore, is MQLib really catering to this specific case of QUBO without linear terms?

Comment: I used both, maybe two years back. At the time, I think qbsolv was tabu search in Python only. I didn't benchmark it except for my specific problem, so maybe I'm just unlucky, but it didn't feel like an effort towards a state of the art solver

Comment: MQlib has algorithms both for Max-Cut and for Qubo, and converts automatically between both

Comment: I'm very interested by the results if you run benchmarks between them!

Answer (score 4):

Maxcut with CPLEX CPOptimizer in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/maxcutcpo.mod

```
using CP;

execute
{
  // time limit 10 s
  cp.param.timelimit=10;
}

int n=400;
range r=1..n;

// Random graph  
float edge_prob=0.5;
int  weight_range=10;
int big=100000;
 
tuple t
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

{t} s={<i,j> | ordered i,j in r};

int w[i in r][j in r]=(i<=j)?((rand(big)<=big*edge_prob)?rand(weight_range):0):0;

// end of random graph

//int n=4;
//range r=1..n;
//float w[r][r]=
//
//[[ 0. , 8. ,-9. , 0.],
// [ 8. , 0. , 7. , 9.],
// [-9. , 7.  ,0., -8.],
// [ 0. , 9., -8. , 0.]];

assert card(s)==n*(n-1) div 2;

 // x is the unknown and 0 or 1 means in one or the other side of the fence
 dvar boolean x[r];
 
 dexpr float obj=2*sum(<i,j> in s) w[i][j]*(x[i]!=x[j]);
 
 maximize obj;
 
 subject to
 {
   // break symmetry
   x[1]==1;
 }
 
 {int} x1={i| i in r:x[i]==1};
 
 execute
 {
   writeln("objective = ",obj);
   writeln("x set to 1 : ",x1);
 }
```

With CPLEX MP at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/maxcut.mod

```
int n=400;
range r=1..n;

// Random graph  
float edge_prob=0.5;
int  weight_range=10;
int big=100000;
 
tuple t
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

{t} s={<i,j> | ordered i,j in r};

int w[i in r][j in r]=(i<=j)?((rand(big)<=big*edge_prob)?rand(weight_range):0):0;

// end of random graph

//int n=4;
//range r=1..n;
//float w[r][r]=
//
//[[ 0. , 8. ,-9. , 0.],
// [ 8. , 0. , 7. , 9.],
// [-9. , 7.  ,0., -8.],
// [ 0. , 9., -8. , 0.]];

assert card(s)==n*(n-1) div 2;

 // x is the unknown and 0 or 1 means in one or the other side of the fence
 dvar boolean x[r];
 
 dexpr float obj=2*sum(<i,j> in s) w[i][j]*x[i]*(1-x[j]);
 
 maximize obj;
 
 subject to
 {
   
 }
 
 {int} x1={i| i in r:x[i]==1};
 
 execute
 {
   writeln("objective = ",obj);
   writeln("x set to 1 : ",x1);
 }
```

and IBM Quantum Qiskit at https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/optimization/6_examples_max_cut_and_tsp.html